# What is the difference between the Azure Identity and MSAL libraries for Python?

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

EDIT: Correct links

Dumb question, but would be great if someone could shed some light for me.

As far as I understand, MSAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) and Azure Identity (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity) let me do very similar things. In addition, both look to be officially supported by Microsoft so seems weird to have two very similar "official" libraries.

Can someone help me understand what the difference is?

Comment: the both links point to the same repo, did you mean [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) vs [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python)?

Comment: Sorry I had a wrong link in there, fixed now!

Answer (score 9):

I just found this:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/299

and also this one relating to the same 2 libraries in JavaScript:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/12565

They both seem to tell a similar story - the Azure Identity library utilises MSAL, so it builds on top of it and provides additional services. However, there might be advanced features of MSAL not exposed by Azure Identity.